# Print specific lines based on text in text-file in ||Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains lots of text however, I only want specific lines/characters printed out. How can do I this?

**Example Text-file**

```
  edit 29
    set status enable
    set sender-pattern-type default
    set sender-pattern *
    set recipient-pattern-type default
    set recipient-pattern *
    set sender-ip-type ip-group
    set sender-ip-group 
    set reverse-dns-pattern *
    set reverse-dns-pattern-regexp no
    set authenticated any
    unset tls-profile
    set action relay
    set comment
```

I want to print only lines that contain `edit`, `set action` and `set comment`.

**How I want it**

```
edit 29
set action relay xyz
set comment xyz
edit 30
set action relay abc
set comment acb
etc.
```

Current code:

```
# Save results of command in "Output" while splitting one whole output line into multiple lines (original output).
output = "".join(ssh_stdout.readlines())

# Save SSH output to a text-file.
file = open('outputFortimail.txt', "w")
file.write(output)
file.close()

file.write("\n".join(
    line for line in file.split("\n") if any(line.startswith(x)
                                               for x in
                                               ["edit:", "set sender-ip-mask:", "set comment:", "unset comment"])))
file.close()
```

Comment: The numbers on the side are the line numbers or are they written on the txt file?

Comment: Just sidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on newline, filter, and join back on newline:

```py
"\n".join(
    line for line in contents.split("\n") if any(line.startswith(x) for x in ["Name:", "Type:", "Area:"])
)
```

Where your file is in the string `contents`.

Comment: I am getting the error AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'. I will update my main post to give a better sight of view.

Comment: If it's a file object, then omit the `.split("\n")`.